# WebApi delegating handler - Accessing HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using the below code:

```
protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    UriBuilder forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
    //remove the proxy port and replace with an Http port
    forwardUri.Port = 1671;
    //send it on to the requested URL
    request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        request.Content = null;
    try
    {

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            ManageOnline(response.RequestMessage);
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The issue happens inside the `ManageOnline` method:

```
private void ManageOnline(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    switch (request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery)
    {
        case @"/token":
            {
                //let's get Content Body contents here
                string jsonContent = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                _cacheHandler.AddUser(jsonContent);
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I get a ***request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'***

However if I run the `ManageOnline(response.RequestMessage);` before the `var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);` it works.

Is there anyway to overcome this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I do not get it: `...if I run it before that it works`. In the failing code, you call `SendAsync` before `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`?

Comment: If I run the ``ManageOnline(response.RequestMessage);`` before the ``var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`` it works.

Comment: It looks like that after calling your `SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)` member, the `request` object gets disposed of. In other words, it might be that the problem is in the code that calls your first code snippet.

Comment: @Sjips exactly, that's the issue. So my question is how to avoid that. Is there anyway to keep the request? A shallow copy or something .. Thanks

Comment: OK, that helps me understand the problem. Do you have a line such as `request.Dispose();` in your calling code? That should be removed.

Comment: @Sjips No I don't have any.

Comment: Avoid using `.Result` and use the async/await pattern instead. Like this: `string jsonContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`